# Why does the load event get called with ProgressEvent object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load binary data asynchronously in the browser:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "test.bin");
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
req.addEventListener("load", function(res) {
   var arrayBuffer = res.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
   ...
```

but the load event that gets triggered has a `res` object that is a `ProgressEvent`.

Is that normal? I'm using chrome and reading the docs on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Why are the docs wrong? This should skip the progress events, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs aren't wrong and neither are you. The response object is a ProgressEvent from the `load` event. In order to get access to the response you need to point back to the original request (`req`) in your case.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "test.bin");
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
req.addEventListener('load', function(progress) {
  var arrayBuffer = req.response;
});
```

The ProgressEvent also has access to the source via `currentTarget`. For example:

```
req.addEventListener("load", function(progress) {
  var arrayBuffer = res.currentTarget.response
});
```

And here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/08zm9urL/1/

**Also Note**:

You cannot access `responseText` when the `responseType` is `arraybuffer`. It must be either an empty string or `text`.

> If responseType is set to anything other than the empty string or "text", accessing responseText will throw InvalidStateError exception.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText

Answer (score 0):

`req.onload` is for handling the response while `req.addEventListener("load", ...` is for monitoring progress, as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. From MDN: `oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);` that's a little misleading.

Comment: Agree - the title of that section is "Monitoring Progress".

Comment: Yes, I realized after you said it. I thought the addEventListener was a newer (and preferred way), and that the load event was replacing the onload handler in the newer framework. But whatever it works now. Thanks.

Comment: if you're looking for newer, consider using the fetch api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: `req.onload` and `req.addEventListner('load')` are for the same event and for the same purpose "when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading."